# grails. Domain class. 1:m

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i have domain classes:

```
package test

class Credit {

 String name;


 static hasMany = [debts : Debt]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and

```
package test

class Debt {


 Integer amount;
 Date date;


 static belongsTo =[credits: Credit]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Need: select `max: 10`; `order: "desc"`; `sort: "date"` rows of Debt associated with the `Сredit.get(id)`

How can i do it?

**solution:**

```
Debt.findAllByCredits(Credit.get(params.id),[max:10, sort:"date",order:"desc"])
```

but next question about this example:

why, this code work:

```
def ok = Debt.findAllByCredits(Credit.get(params.id),[max:10, sort:"date",order:"desc"])


println "true:" + ok
```

but this code not work correct:

```
def dd = new Debt(credits: Credit.get(params.id))

def wrong =Debt.findAll(dd)

println "no: "+ wrong
```

all time return all records in table, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like

```
 def hql = "select d from Debt d where credits = ? order by d.date desc"
 Debt.findAll(hql, [credit], [max:10])
```

you might have to tweak that, but something similar should work.  Also note, I am assuming that you have an instance of credit that is the parent of the Debts.

You can also use the methods Grails generates dynamically at runtime, based on the properties of your classes

```
Debt.findAllByCredit(credit,  [max:10,sort:"date",order:"desc"]
```

again, you will need a reference to a credit object.

Check out the docs at

http://grails.org/doc/latest/

specifically the section on findAll and findAllBy under Domain Classes in the left hand nav.

Comment: now i read doc, and i see, that i cant use: findAllByCredit - This method does not exist, i can use only findAllByAmount and findAllByDate and no more :(

Comment: @user471011 thats because you have a property credits, not credit.

Comment: you're right! Debt.findAllByCredits(Credit.get(params.id),[max:10, sort:"date",order:"desc"]) - works!!!